# Minimizing $\cot^2 A +\cot^2 B + \cot^2 C$ for $A+B+C=\pi$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, optimization, triangles

> If $A + B + C = \pi$, then find the minimum value of $\cot^2 A +\cot^2 B + \cot^2 C$.

I don't know how to solve it. And can you please mention the used formulas first.

What I can see is that if one of the angles $A$, $B$, $C$ is small, then the value $\cot^2A$ or $\cot^2B$ or $\cot^2C$ will be big. So I want to make angles big (more precisely, close to $\pi/2$, where cotangent is zero), but the condition $A+B+C=\pi$ prevents me from making all three of them very big .

I can see that if $A=B=C=\frac\pi3$, then I get $\cot A=\cot B=\cot C=\frac1{\sqrt3}$ and $\cot^2A+\cot^2B+\cot^2C=1$. But I do not know whether this is indeed minimum. (According to WolframAlpha [this is the minimum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+cot%5E2x%2Bcot%5E2y%2Bcot%5E2z+for+x%2By%2Bz%3Dpi). However, I would like to see some proof of this fact.)

Comment: But we are not getting a value for cot C in this way. cot C can be both +ve or -ve of cot( A+B ) depending on if C>90` or <90`

Comment: At the moment I cannot see an easy way to do it. The answer is 1 with $A=B=C$. But so far I have only proved it by a fairly complicated argument.

Comment: Can you at least find some values of this expressions? For example, what you get for $A=B=C$? What you get if $A=B$ and $C$ is very small? Based on this, are you able to guess what the result might be?

Comment: @MartinSleziak The last thing you want is $A,B$ or $C$ small!

Comment: @almagest I know. I am not sure the OP does see this and experimenting might help them. Also it would be good if the OP added [some context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960). This would be one possibility how to do that. (You see that there are already two close votes on the question. In both case the close reason is missing context.)

Comment: BTW you can find [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624739/in-a-triangle-abc-evaluation-of-minimum-value-of-cot2-a-cot2-b-cot2-c) among related questions (in the sidebar on the right). I am not sure whether it should be considered duplicate. (It asks about the same inequality, but mostly about a specific proof provided by the OP.)

Comment: @JamilAhmed On this site you are supposed to provide some context to your question. For example, by saying what the source of the question is, or what your own thoughts about the problem are. I recommend reading [How to ask a good question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), which covers also this. (This could also help you understand why your previous questions got closed.)

Comment: In this case I have tried to edit your post to add some context. Of course, you can improve it further. (You might have have seen other similar problems, so you might have some idea what things could be used. You could tell us where you have seen this problem.) We will see whether this edit will be sufficient to [prevent this question from getting closed](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/645002).

Comment: $\cot(\pi - A - B) = -\cot(A+B)$ what is $\pm ve$?

Comment: This question was closed as a duplicate of [In a $\triangle ABC,$ Evaluation of minimum value of $\cot^2 A+\cot^2 B+\cot^2 C$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624739/in-a-triangle-abc-evaluation-of-minimum-value-of-cot2-a-cot2-b-cot2-c). I am not sure that this is a correct decision, since the other question asks about a specific approach how to prove this, not about any proof in general. I have asked also in the [dedicated chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2165/2016/6/16) what hsould be done with this.

Comment: +ve means positive. And I will try and ask better questions.

Comment: Yes, I am asking for a general proof and not where the equality holds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put $x=\cot A,y=\cot B$. Using the standard formulae we have $z=\cot C=-\cot(A+B)=\frac{1-xy}{x+y}$. So we want to minimize $$f(x,y)=\frac{(x^2+y^2)(x+y)^2+(xy-1)^2}{(x+y)^2}$$ where $x,y$ can take any real values.

If we want to minimize $(x^2+y^2)(x+y)^2+x^2y^2-2xy+1$ subject to $x+y=k$, then using Lagrange multipliers we find $4x^3-2y+6x^2y+6xy^2+2y^3=\lambda=-2x+2x^3+6yx^2+6xy^2+4y^3$ and so $x=y$ or $x^2+xy+y^2=0$. Note that this result is independent of $k$. Note also that $f(x,y)$ is large for $|x|$ or $|y|$ large, so the minimum will occur at a stationary point.

If $x=y$ then we want to minimize $2x^2+\frac{(x^2-1)^2}{4x^2}{4x^2}$. Differentiating, this has a minimum at $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$ that makes $A=B=C=\frac{\pi}{3}$ and the minimum value 1.

If $x^2+xy+y^2=0$, then $-xy=x^2+y^2\ge0$. But $0\le(x+y)^2=x^2+xy+y^2+xy=xy$, so we must have $xy=0$ and hence also $x^2+y^2=0$ and so $x=y=0$, which clearly does not yield a minimum.

----------Added later, courtesy of Martin Sleziak ---------

I am not particularly happy with the argument above, which seems like using a hammer to crack a nut. The OP in this earlier question [In a $\triangle ABC,$ Evaluation of minimum value of $\cot^2 A+\cot^2 B+\cot^2 C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624739/in-a-triangle-abc-evaluation-of-minimum-value-of-cot2-a-cot2-b-cot2-c) provided a much simpler argument:

By AM/GM we have $\cot^2A+\cot^2B\ge 2\cot A\cot B$, and similarly $\cot^2B+\cot^2C\ge 2\cot B\cot C$ and $\cot^2C+\cot^2A\ge 2\cot C\cot A$ so we have $$\cot^2A+\cot^2B+\cot^2C\ge \cot A\cot B+\cot B\cot C+\cot C\cot A$$ But now by the formula at the start we have $\cot C(\cot A+\cot B)=1-\cot A\cot B$ which gives immediately $$\cot^2A+\cot^2B+\cot^2C\ge1$$
Instead of using AM/GM we could also use the rearrangement inequality.

If you like that argument upvote his question rather than this answer!

Comment: The second method was easier, btw. It answered my question. P.s. What are Lagrange multipliers ? You mentioned them in the first method.

Comment: Yes, the second method is neat. Look up the rearrangement inequality (if you have not met it) - it is often useful. Lagrange multipliers is a standard way of using calculus to fine maxima/minima for expressions is several variables subject to constraints.

Answer (score 6):

For another way, since $\cot^2x$ is convex when $x \in [0,\pi]$ and we need to worry only of positive $x$, so by Jensen's inequality:
$$ \sum_{cyc} \cot^2 A \geqslant 3 \cot^2\frac{A+B+C}3=1$$

As equality is possible when $A=B=C=\frac{\pi}3$, we have the minimum.

Comment: BTW this is precisely the argument discussed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624739/in-a-triangle-abc-evaluation-of-minimum-value-of-cot2-a-cot2-b-cot2-c).

Answer (score 3):

Since the cotangent function is odd, we may assume $A,B,C\geq 0$ without loss of generality.
 So $A,B,C$ are the angles of a triangle. Let we deal first with the case of an acute triangle.
 By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:

$$\cot(A)^2+\cot(B)^2+\cot(C)^2 \geq 3\left(\frac{\cot A+\cot B+\cot C}{3}\right)^2 = \frac{\cot(\omega)^2}{3}$$
where $\omega$ is the [Brocard angle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrocardAngle.html). Since $\omega\leq\frac{\pi}{6}$,

> $$ \cot(A)^2+\cot(B)^2+\cot(C)^2 \geq \color{red}{1}$$

and equality is attained by the equilateral triangle. Now we may deal with the obtuse case, and assume $A\geq \frac{\pi}{2}$. So $B,C$ are acute angles and their sum does not exceed $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Since the $\cot^2$ function is convex and decreasing on the interval $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, we have:
$$ \cot^2(B)+\cot^2(C) \geq 2\cot^2\left(\frac{B+C}{2}\right)\geq 2\cot^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=2 $$
and we are done.